# Dependency Injection with Superglobals?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, superglobals

I'm using dependency injection wherever possible in my application.

I've got a Request class that works with superglobals, but to me it feels a little bit weird; injecting superglobals. Isn't it safe to say that superglobals will always be there and instead of injecting them I could just call them directly in the class (tightly coupled)?

**Class: Request**

```
public function __construct($get, $post, $server) { ... }
```

**Class: Session**

```
public function __construct() { session_start(); }
```

This last one is a little bit tricky because in this constructor I am starting the session with `session_start()` and `$_SESSION` is only defined **after** the session has been started, so I cannot inject that. However, I could set it with a setter after instantiating the class.

How should I work with superglobals when it comes to OOP?

Do I just couple them tightly with classes or should I still just inject them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is kind of confusing. What you can do is this:

```
class Request {
    public function __construct($getData, $postData, $serverData) { ... }
}

new Request($_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER);
```

When it comes to sessions, you'd better wrap it into an object:

```
class Session {
    public function __construct() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Another approach is to use Lazy Initialization:

```
class LazySession {
    private $isStarted = false;
    public function __construct() {

    }

    private function verifyAndStart() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    }

    public function set(...) {
        $this->verifyAndStart();
        // ...
    }

    public function set(...) {
        $this->verifyAndStart();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can inject it anywhere, but the session will only be created when needed. Notice that the session MUST be created before any output.

### Edit:

I was in a hurry when first answered this, but just to make things clear: you cannot decouple everything. What should be decoupled is the implementation of session variables access and its client objects.

For example, you define something like this:

```
interface SessionStorageInterface {
    public function get($key);
    public function set($key, $value);
    public function remove($key);
    public function clear();
}
```

If you don't want to rewrite PHP built in session system, you'd have to do something like:

```
final class DefaultSessionStorage implements SessionStorageInterface {
    protected function start() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION))
            session_start();
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[(string) $key] = $value;
    }

    //...
}
```

If you want to change this and hold your session in a database, you could create something like:

```
final class DbSessionStorage implements SessionStorageInterface {
    private $id;
    private $dbStorage;
    private $definition;

    public function __construct($sessionId, DbStorage $storage, StorageDefinition $def) {
        $this->id = $sessionId;
        $this->dbStorage = $storage;
        $this->definition = $def;
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $data = [
            $this->def->getField(StorageDefinition::IDENTIFIER) => $this->id,
            $this->def->getField(StorageDefinition::KEY) => $key,
            $this->def->getField(StorageDefinition::KEY) => $value,
        ];

        try {
            $this->dbStorage->save($def->getContainer(), $data);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // does something...
        }
    }
    // other methods omitted for brevity...
}
```

The important thing is that when you have some class that depends on a session storage, you declare it like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage) {
        // ...
    }
}

$obj1 = new SomeClass(new DefaultSessionStorage());
$obj2 = new SomeClass(new DbSessionStorage(...));
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm guessing that get, post, server and session data will **always** be in $_POST, $_GET, $_SERVER, $_SESSION superglobals. Why do you inject them in the Request class, but have $_SESSION tightly coupled in the LazySession class?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. PHP is not well designed. This is one implementation, but you can for sure create others and use interfaces to decouple your code. Then you'll be able to do unit testing and mocking...

Comment: You can inject anything in this `Request` class. You are the boss now. It is actually less coupled than your original idea...